# How to deserialize a JSON array of arrays of name-value pairs into a List<MyClass>

Tags: c#, jquery, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a JSON string that I'm trying to deserialize into a list of the following class:

```
public class Selection
{
    public Int64 id { get; set; }
    public bool view { get; set; }
    public bool edit { get; set; }
    public bool broad { get; set; }
}
```

This is my JSON string that I get:

```
[
    [
        {"name":"id", "value":0},
        {"name":"view", "value":true},
        {"name":"edit", "value":false},
        {"name":"broad", "value":false}
    ],
    [
        {"name":"id", "value":0},
        {"name":"view", "value":false},
        {"name":"edit", "value":false},
        {"name":"broad", "value":false}
    ],
    [
        {"name":"id", "value":0},
        {"name":"view", "value":true},
        {"name":"edit", "value":false},
        {"name":"broad", "value":false}
    ],
    [
        {"name":"id", "value":0},
        {"name":"view", "value":true},
        {"name":"edit", "value":false},
        {"name":"broad", "value":false}
    ],
    [
        {"name":"id", "value":0},
        {"name":"view", "value":false},
        {"name":"edit", "value":false},
        {"name":"broad", "value":false}
    ],
    [
        {"name":"id", "value":0},
        {"name":"view", "value":false},
        {"name":"edit", "value":false},
        {"name":"broad", "value":false}
    ],
    [
        {"name":"id", "value":0},
        {"name":"view", "value":false},
        {"name":"edit", "value":false},
        {"name":"broad", "value":false}
    ],
    [
        {"name":"id", "value":0},
        {"name":"view", "value":false},
        {"name":"edit", "value":false},
        {"name":"broad", "value":false}
    ],
    [
        {"name":"id", "value":0},
        {"name":"view", "value":false},
        {"name":"edit", "value":false},
        {"name":"broad", "value":false}
    ],
    [
        {"name":"id", "value":0},
        {"name":"view", "value":false},
        {"name":"edit", "value":false},
        {"name":"broad", "value":false}
    ]
]
```

This is how I'm calling deserialization:

```
 var selection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Selection>>(param.selection);
```

But I'm getting this error:

[image]

Do I need another type of format?

Comment: You don't show how you call deserialization, i think you try to deserialize your json as a single element, but it's an array.

Comment: Just update it, thanks

Comment: You have an array of arrays. Remove the outer array and your code will work. Or you could use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Selection>>()`, but frankly that's pretty redundant.

Comment: how is your json created? This json is invalid for the object you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because the shape of the JSON does not match the structure you are trying to deserialize into.  Your JSON represents an array of arrays of name-value pair objects, but you are trying to deserialize into a `List<Selection>`.  To deserialize into the class you have defined, you will need to use a custom `JsonConverter` like this:

```
public class SelectionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Selection);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = new JObject(
            JArray.Load(reader)
                  .Children<JObject>()
                  .Select(jo => new JProperty((string)jo["name"], jo["value"]))
            );
        var selection = new Selection();
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), selection);
        return selection;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, you can deserialize like this:

```
var selection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Selection>>(param.selection, new SelectionConverter());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pgAvUA

Answer (score 0):

This JSON will not be parsed easily, you have in the JSON the name of the params as values of the dictionary.
The best this to do is to change the JSON to be something like:

```
[
{
        id :12345,
        view:true,
        edit : true,
        broad :true
},
.....
]
```

And like this it will be parsed using the same code.

If you **can't** change the JSON, then your code will have to use reflection to set properties. Or parse as Dictionary and loop over it and for each property set it value into new object.

Answer (score -1):

please find the below explanation to serialise the j son string .
Here in my example i am having a string with student details as shown below.

```
  string json = @"{""data"":[{""id"":""1"",""name"":""A""}, {""id"":""2"",""name"":""B""}, {""id"":""3"",""name"":""C""}, {""id"":""5"",""name"":""D""}]}";
```

I am using the below class structure as below.

```
   public class Students
   {
       public List<StudentDetails> data { get; set; }
   }
   public class StudentDetails
   {
       public string id { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }



   }
```

use below line of code to serialise the json string

```
 Students studentdetails = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Students>(json);
```

here the JavaScriptSerializer() class is present in the system.Web.Extensions  assembly.
Please mark this as answer,if this helps.

Comment: Your JSON doesn't match the structure of the JSON in the question.  Your answer also does not use Json.Net as was tagged in the original question.